# Check/uncheck all checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

How to check / uncheck checkbox onclick td .Please suggest some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be as simple as

```
jQuery(function($){
    var chkbox = $('#chkall'), chks = $(':checkbox').not(chkbox);
    $('#chkall_head').click(function(event){
        if(!$(event.target).is(chkbox)){
            chkbox.prop('checked', !chkbox.is(':checked'))
        }
        chks.prop('checked', chkbox.is(':checked'))
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PanVZ)

Comment: @Sravanthi jquery version used

Comment: @ Arun P Johny ok thanks i used attr instead of prop but onclick checbox that didnt work can you help me

Comment: @Sravanthi without recreating the problem using a fiddle it is difficult... also mention the jquery version used

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your markup a little bit. Try utilizing the `for` attribute which will automatically bind the text with the corresponding text. Make sure it contains the id of the checkbox you want to bind it to. This is how your markup should look like: (note the addition of `label` with `for` attribute)

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="chkall_head">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkall" name="chkall" />
            </th>
            <th>
                <label for="chkall">Check all</label> 
                <!-- ^^ check this line - chkall is the id the check box ^^-->
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="chk1">Checkbox 1</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="chk2">Checkbox 2</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Next, try using `change` instead of the `click`. Since you used the `for` attribute, you dont need to write to a seperate click event for header. Here's the JS :

```
$("#chkall").change(function () {
    $("tbody").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/FBv8B/

Corrected demo of fiddle in Arun's answer's comments : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/FBv8B/2/